# Accessing XML after foreach using DomDocument

Tags: php, xml

I am using DomDocument to access XML data but I am not able to access.

```
    $xmlstring =<<<XML
    <CcyTbl>
    <CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>AFGHANISTAN</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>Afghani</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>AFN</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>971</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
    </CcyNtry>
    <CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>ÅLAND ISLANDS</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>Euro</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>978</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
    </CcyNtry>
    <CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>ALBANIA</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>Lek</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>ALL</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>008</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
    </CcyNtry>
    <CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>ALGERIA</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>Algerian Dinar</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>DZD</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>012</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
    </CcyNtry>
    <CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>AMERICAN SAMOA</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>US Dollar</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>840</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
    </CcyNtry>
    </CcyTbl>
    XML;
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $doc->loadXML( utf8_encode($xmlstring));
    $countries = $doc->getElementsByTagName('CcyNtry');
    foreach($countries as $country){
    print_r($country->nodeValue);die();

    }
```

This shows

```
AFGHANISTAN Afghani AFN 971 2
```

But i want to access individual items like CtryNm,CcyNm,Ccy

I tried to access

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $doc->loadXML( utf8_encode($xmlstring));
    $countries = $doc->getElementsByTagName('CcyNtry');
    foreach($countries as $country){
      echo $country->CtryNm;die();

    }
```

> Undefined property: DOMElement::$CtryNm

Comment: Could you provide the full code? The first example contains a parse error.

Comment: You need to move the XML; to the first line

Comment: Yes you need to try this  $countries = $doc->getElementsByTagName('CcyTbl');

Comment: You can't do it with DOM, try simplexml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. From the below you can access all elements in the XML

```
$simple = "<CcyTbl>
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>AFGHANISTAN</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>Afghani</CcyNm>
<Ccy>AFN</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>971</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>ÅLAND ISLANDS</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>Euro</CcyNm>
<Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>978</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>ALBANIA</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>Lek</CcyNm>
<Ccy>ALL</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>008</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>ALGERIA</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>Algerian Dinar</CcyNm>
<Ccy>DZD</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>012</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>AMERICAN SAMOA</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>US Dollar</CcyNm>
<Ccy>USD</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>840</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
</CcyTbl>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(new SimpleXMLElement($simple));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML(utf8_encode($xmlstring));

$countries = $doc->firstChild->getElementsByTagName('CcyNtry');

foreach($countries as $country){
    echo $country->getElementsByTagName('CtryNm')->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

This will get all of the `CtryNm's`. Simply replace `CtryNm` with the name of the tag you want to retrieve. You should probably look into [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your XML nodes as object properties, then use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead of DOMDocument it will be much easier to use.

Here is an example for your XML string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
foreach ($xml->CcyNtry as $country) {
    echo $country->CtryNm . "\n";
}
```

That same way you can access other nodes of your XML as object properties.